# xxx-form-encoded to application/json

Tags: node.js, json, postman

My login functionalities in the backend accepts the parameters in xxx-form-encoded format from POSTMAN .. I am getting error when I change the format to application/json . Any thoughts on how to receive the request.body ?

```
authenticate: function(req, res, next) {
        userModel.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, userInfo){
                    if (err) {
                        next(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`The bcrypt value: ${bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, userInfo.password)}`)
                        if(userInfo != null && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, userInfo.password)) {

                         const token = jwt.sign({id: userInfo._id}, req.app.get('secret'), { expiresIn: '1h' }); 

                         res.json({status:"success", message: "user found!!!", data:{user: userInfo, token:token}});    

                        }else{

                            res.json({status:"error", message: "Invalid email/password!!!", data:null});

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a middleware which parses your request body to json.

You can use `body-parser` to acheive it.

if you are using express you can do this to acheive it:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({}));//this line is required to tell your app to parse the body as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

From body-parser docs :

> **bodyParser.urlencoded([options])**
>
> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies and only looks
> at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option.
> This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports
> automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
>
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the
> request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This object will
> contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array
> (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).

Read [body-parser documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for details.

Comment: `bodyParser` is also available as a property of the `express` variable, obviating the need for another dependency.